# F#: Create an Async from a function which takes a callback and returns a cancelation handle

Tags: asynchronous, f#, ffi

I'm new to F# and trying to write a wrapper module around a C library. The C library has a function with this signature:

```c
handle* call_callback(void (*callback)(int));
```

It also has a function that allows the above function to be cancelled by taking the `handle*`:

```c
void cancel_callback(handle* h);
```

I want to wrap this pair of functions into an `Async`.

I'm familiar with `Async.FromContinuations` and, if it weren't for the need to call `cancel_callback` I could wrap `call_callback` like this:

```ml
let my_async = Async.FromContinuations(fun (succ, err, cancel) -> 
        let handle = call_callback(succ)
    )
```

This problem is that I need to get a hold of `handle` and make sure that `cancel_callback(handle)` gets called if this Async gets cancelled. I can't see a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There's an Async.OnCancel method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.oncancel-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) that you can await on which will invoke upon cancelled tasks. Alternatively just wrap it up in a IDisposable and "use" it in your async workflow if you want it to be called on success, cancel, and failure cases. Hopefully I've understood your use case correctly.

```
async {
    use _ = { new IDisposable with member __.Dispose() = cancel_callback() }
    // Or if only on Cancel case
    use! cancelHandler = Async.OnCancel(fun () -> cancel_callback())
    // Do rest of your workflow here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting interop to unmanaged code to work is tricky, especially if you have callbacks. There are many things that can trip you up like calling conventions. I can therefore give no guarantees that code below works but perhaps it's something you can start from and tweak to a state that works for you.

Usually I define interop code in C# but F# do support it as well.

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

// Contains F# PInvkoe for the call_callback, cancel_callback
//  assuming they are exported by "my.dll"
//  Note this relies on standard calling convention (default in Windows)
module CallbackInterop =
  // handle* call_callback(void (*callback)(int));
  [<DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)>]
  extern nativeint call_callback(nativeint callback);

  // void cancel_callback(handle* h);
  [<DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)>]
  extern void cancel_callback(nativeint h);

type CallbackDelegate = delegate of int -> unit

// The CallbackInterop is very low-level, ManagedCallback is a bridge between
//  low-level unmanaged function pointers and .NET managed delegates
type ManagedCallback (callback : ManagedCallback -> int -> unit) =
  let mutable ghnd  = Unchecked.defaultof<GCHandle>
  let mutable del   = Unchecked.defaultof<Delegate>
  let mutable cptr  = IntPtr.Zero
  let mutable hnd   = IntPtr.Zero

  member x.Callback (i :int) : unit = callback x i

  member x.Start () =
    // Creates a delegate for x.Callback
    del   <- CallbackDelegate                       x.Callback
    // Prevents collection of the Delegate while we are waiting for 
    //  a callback and also prevents the GC from moving the Delegate around
    //  The delegate also references the ManagedCallback so it also prevents the 
    //  the collection of ManagedCallback
    ghnd  <- GCHandle.Alloc                         (del, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    // Create function pointer from pinned delegate
    cptr  <- Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate  del
    // Register the function pointer and get a handle back
    // After this we are ready for callbacks
    hnd   <- CallbackInterop.call_callback          cptr

  interface IDisposable with
    member x.Dispose () = 
      // Usually when implementing unmanaged interop one implements a finalizer
      //  but due to the setup this object can't be collected while the callback is active
      //  This means no need for finalizer
      try
        let h = hnd

        // Reset all members
        hnd   <- IntPtr.Zero
        cptr  <- IntPtr.Zero
        del   <- Unchecked.defaultof<Delegate>

        // Cancel callback if active
        if h <> IntPtr.Zero then
          CallbackInterop.cancel_callback h
      finally
        // Free the GCHandle, ensuring the delegate and ManagedCallback can now be collected
        if ghnd <> Unchecked.defaultof<GCHandle> then
          ghnd.Free ()
          ghnd <- Unchecked.defaultof<GCHandle>

// An async workflow that uses the managed callback
let managedCallback : Async<int> =
  Async.FromContinuations <| fun (onSuccess, _, _) ->
    // onSuccess is called on success, the other callbacks on failure
    //  and cancellations, call them as needed

    // The callback for the ManagedCallback, we dispose the callback when we receive a value
    //  and then call onSuccess
    let cb (mc : ManagedCallback) i =
      let d : IDisposable = mc :> IDisposable
      d.Dispose ()
      onSuccess i

    // Setup and start the ManagedCallback
    let mc = new ManagedCallback (cb)
    mc.Start ()
```